# Is there a way to set the iPhone keyboard to all caps without going through delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, capitalization

I have a textfield that can switch between a numpad and an alphanumeric keyboard (for design reasons). Here's the code:

```
self.tfID.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
[self.tfID reloadInputViews];
```

The problem is that when I switch from numpad to alphanumeric, it doesn't automatically turn on the caps even though that field is set to UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters. I don't want to do this through the delegate because I want to still allow the user to enter in lowercase characters if they choose so. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: After the first character is typed, the caps lock is turned back on so only the first character is lowercased.

Comment: So essentially you want caps lock on by default, right?

Comment: It's only not on for the first character typed after switching the keyboard. I'm guessing it has something to do with preserving the state of the keyboard during the transition. The numpad has no caps so when you go to the alphanumeric keyboard, it also has no caps since the state is saved. But only for the first character after the transition. I added it as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it works. Instead of calling reloadInputViews on your textfield, if you call resignFirstResponder immediately followed by a becomeFirstResponder on your textfield it will auto switch to all caps again for the first character. This does slightly show the animation from lower case keys to all caps keys, but it does achieve your functional goal of getting back to all caps automatically for that first character.

```
self.tfID.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
[self.tfID resignFirstResponder];
[self.tfID becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but I ended up doing this after: [self.tfID reloadInputViews]; because the keyboard detection and resizing code I have doesn't run without it.

Comment: Ok, cool. I found that the animation of the all caps switch was less noticible if you did not call reloadInputViews. I am glad you got a working solution.